# PHP & GD - transparent background being filled with nearby color

Tags: php, image-processing, transparency, gd

I know PHP+GD Transparency issues have been beat to death on this and many other sites, but I've followed all the recommendations and I can't seem to fix my issue.

First, the explanation:

I am trying to overlay one image on top of another one.  They both have areas that are transparent.  As a demo that I know should look a particular way, I am trying to overlay a checkmark on top of a blue arrow shape that I created.

Here are the two images:

[image: check mark]

[image: blue arrow]

Now to my code:

I am using a library/API that I built to take a TINY bit of the pain away from editing images with PHP+GD.  It's still in it's infancy, but the pertinent files are:

[The Base Class](https://github.com/rockerest/nox/tree/master/classes/backbone/ImageBase.php)
[The Main Loader](https://github.com/rockerest/nox/tree/master/classes/backbone/Image.php)
[The (poorly named) Combine Class](https://github.com/rockerest/nox/tree/master/classes/backbone/ImageCombine.php)

I am running the code using the following script:

```
<?php
    require_once('Image.php');

    header("Content-Type: image/png");

    $img = new Image();
    $over = new Image();

    $img->source = "arrow.png";
    $over->source = "chk-done_24.png";

    $img->Combine->Overlay($over, 20, 20, 0, 0, $over->width, $over->height);
    $img->output();
    $img->clean();
    unset($img);
?>
```

I expect the output to be something like this:

[image: Combined images]

But instead I get this:

[image: Square bottom]

I would totally understand the issue **if the filled area was white or black**, but filling with the *blue color* just doesn't make any sense to me.

In the Combine Class I linked above, I have also tried [imagecopy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php), [imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php), and the vanilla [imagecopymerge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php), both with similar results.

I'm at a total loss.

### Edit:

To be clear, my question is this:  What part of my code is incorrect?  Why is it filling the transparent area with a color (instead of black or white) and how can I fix it while still maintaining the ability to merge images with transparency?

### Update:

Please note, when a new Image object is created, it calls `newImage` which contains the following code:

```
$this->handle = imagecreatetruecolor($this->width, $this->height);
imagealphablending($this->handle, false);
imagesavealpha($this->handle, true);
```

I feel like that might be easy to miss.

Comment: you can eaisly do this using GD but anyway . try only using overlay without combining the two images.

Comment: Could it be the method in which you make your arrow file with the transparency?

Comment: @Jared I suppose it's possible.  I'm not an expert on images / transparency, so I wasn't aware that there were different ways to get a totally transparent background.  I'm stepping away from the computer for a few hours, but I'll see if I can get different results on another image later today.

Comment: @rockerest - Well, when I open your original arrow image in Photoshop, it displays as in the combined image (with no transparency on the bottom half). When I Google Photoshop PNG transparency, I see that there are issues with how Photoshop handles this, so you might try to construct your image with a mask or just erase the extra pixels you don't want to display and see if that changes the outcome (which I imagine it would).

Comment: Check what Jared said, it has happened to me before although I do not remember what the problem was, it looked fine in photoshop but was not proper in webpage. It could well be your script is fine but an improperly optimized image can cause this.  If you can try with other transparent images, also could help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that it doesn't matter that you create the handle in `newImage` and call `imagealphablending` and `imagesavealpha` on it, because `loadImage` throws that handle away.

The reason it is "filling" the transparent area with the blue color is that it is not filling the transparent area with anything at all. It it just completely dropping the alpha channel, and the blue color is what happens to be stored in those pixels with an alpha of zero. Note this may be difficult to see in a graphics program, as that program may itself replace completely-transparent pixels with black or white.

As for what is wrong with your code, I can't say for sure as I don't get the same results as you report when I try your existing code. But if I change your `loadImage` to something like this so the source images are forced to true color, it works for me:

```
            private function loadImage()
            {
                    $img = null;
                    switch( $this->type )
                    {
                            case 1:
                                            $img = imagecreatefromgif($this->source);
                                            break;
                            case 2:
                                            $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->source);
                                            break;
                            case 3:
                                            $img = imagecreatefrompng($this->source);
                                            break;
                            default:
                                            break;
                    }
                    if (!$img) return false;
                    $this->handle = imagecreatetruecolor($this->width, $this->height);
                    imagealphablending($this->handle, false);
                    imagesavealpha($this->handle, true);
                    imagecopyresampled($this->handle, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $this->width, $this->height, $this->width, $this->height);
                    return true;
            }
```

(Personally, I prefer ImageMagick over GD).

Comment: You're right on all counts.  I used a transparent image I found on the web and it "worked."  I got a black fill with the two images combined.  I'm going to fix my code so that loaded images are forced to maintain alpha, and when it works, I'll come back here and give you the bounty.  Thanks for the code sample!

Comment: thanks for the help, this worked.  I'll award the bounty when I can (in an hour, apparently...).